# Can multiple users upload products to the ofbiz ecommerce site using party manager and roles?

Tags: ofbiz

Can I set up the OfBiz party manager in such a way that multiple users can upload their own products to their own catalogs using parties and roles?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in OfBiz, but we are currently developing a freelance project with it. Your user type (or actor) has to belong to a user group and you have to define security permissions for that group then user will be able to add products. But, adding products to their specific catalog is another story. You can take a look at opentaps, where each facility manager can control his/her facility specifically in the "warehouse" application. We also implemented similar functionality for our application. It took 2 hours to understand and implement. But, OfBiz is very intuitive and I am sure that you can easily add this functionality to catalog manager application easily.